# How to make asynchronous co-routines with rxjs observables?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, coroutine

I have dialogue-based protocol.

Questioning side should:

1. generate a question
2. wait for an answer and consume it
3. continue to next question or stop asking

Answering side should:

1. receive a question and show it to user
2. wait for user to answer
3. send the answer to questioning side
4. expect next question or end of iterations

Both sides are asynchronous. Some questions are requested from server. And all answers are from UI events.

How to do it in rxjs-way?

Comment: what's the logic on generating next question

Comment: @FanCheung most of them are requested from server. 
and some of them taken from predefined lists, they go before and after sever generated stuff.

Comment: the key here is really about how you generate the next question, predefine vs dynamic makes a huge difference. The rest are not difficult. Could you paste the logic of the question generation in your question?